# Can I declare const int from reference passed parameter return values?

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization, constants, pass-by-reference

I am wondering if I could somehow declare the following integers as const. Their values are only once changed in the function below.

```
int32_t offset_x, offset_y;
frame1.get()->enlargeForMerge(frame2.get(), offset_x, offset_y);

void SlpFrame::enlargeForMerge(const SlpFrame &frame, int32_t &os_x, int32_t &os_y)
```

Is there some lambda thing etc that can allow me to have something like this:

```
const int32_t offset_x, offset_y => magic[1, 2]()
frame1.get()->enlargeForMerge(frame2.get(), offset_x, offset_y);
```

Where the only difference from the first code is that offset integers are constant from now on. I took a look at the lambda documentation, but it's beyond me.

Comment: Not for 2 separated values. but if wrapped in std::pair or class, it would be possible.

Comment: No, that you can't do. But you can declare your variables non-const with obscure names, and immediately after setting them through your `enlargeForMerge` declare a const reference with normal names to thoses.

Comment: If an object is const, it is const during its entire lifetime. Any attempt to modify it has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```
struct Offset { int x, y; };
```

and then:

```
const Offset offset = bla();
```

where your function either returns an Offset , or you can have it return a `pair` and convert this to Offset or whatever.

Then you can use `offset.x` and `offset.y` instead of `offset_x` etc.

---

Another option is:

```
const std::pair<int32_t, int32_t> offsets = bla();
int32_t const &offset_x = offsets.first;
int32_t const &offset_y = offsets.second;
```

---

Finally, another option is to just not use `const` and keep doing what you're doing.  IMHO, `const` local variables which aren't constant expressions are not a great use; the only purpose is to detect accidental modification later, but if your function is so complicated that you can't tell at a glance whether this is happening then it might be better to refactor the function.

Comment: @RichardHodges fixed, ty

Comment: Good point, that needing const is questionable here. I still wanted to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do with intermediate variable.

```
const auto offset = [&](){
    int32_t offset_x;
    int32_t offset_y;
    frame1.get()->enlargeForMerge(frame2.get(), offset_x, offset_y);
    return std::make_pair(offset_x, offset_y);
}();
const int32_t offset_x = offset.first;
const int32_t offset_y = offset.second;
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Will const auto offset only be executed one time?

Comment: @TiiviTaavi: The lambda is directly called. `offset` is a `pair`, not a lambda.